# Term for descenders interrupting underlines?

Tags: typesetting

Is there a term of art in typesetting to designate the practice of interrupting an underline where it intersects a descender? It's called "skip ink" in CSS, but how do printers and typesetters refer to it?

Also, out of curiosity, how was this done before the days of computer typesetting? Seems like something that might not be doable except by hand-drawing the underline back in the day (?).

Comment: In graphic design and typesetting in general, especially for printed material/documents, underlined text is generally avoided, and rarely used. It's better to use another way to emphasize your text, either italics or bold, etc.  In the past before digital typesetting, when the printer received a typewritten copy of the body text to be used in a print job, underlined text indicated the type was to be set in italics.

Comment: Note also that when a line under text is included as part of a design, such as in a logo, it's often manually drawn to avoid such problems, rather than relying on text formatting attributes.

Comment: Questions like these often end up unanswered which is a shame. Maybe there isn't a term for that specific technique. It doesn't mean there's nothing to be said about it, but if you just ask for a name and no one knows it, the question will never be answered. If you got a term then what would you use it for? Search for articles about it? I doubt they exist in great numbers. Perhaps you could ask a more specific question about what it is about "descenders interrupting underlines" that's giving you trouble?